# Create Contact7 Form programmatically

Tags: forms, plugin-contact-form-7

Is there a way to create a Contact7 Form programmatically?

I mean create the respective post type and fill the custom form fields for example as array and after all generate a shortcode for the created form?

Comment: I cannot find any documented API. Which would require you to dig into the plugin's methods and...

Answer (score 1):

I believe the forms are just post with the type `wpcf7_contact_form`. Query one up and its meta to see how the form settings and other related stuff are saved. Or browse the plugin source.

You should then be able to insert new form posts with `wp_insert_post()`.